# Listview highlight selected item with custom color vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, highlight

Following routine helps highlight a listview selected item with custom color in VB.Net. Have the below code in code module, pass the listview and desired color to get selected items highlighted with given color.

```
Public Sub ListViewHighLightSelectedItem(oListView As ListView, clrHighLightColor As System.Drawing.Color)
    Try
        If oListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            For Each oLVItem As ListViewItem In oListView.Items
                oLVItem.UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
                If oLVItem.Selected = True Then
                    'Selected item
                    For Each oSubItem In oLVItem.SubItems
                        oSubItem.BackColor = clrHighLightColor
                    Next
                Else
                    'Non selected item
                    For Each oSubItem In oLVItem.SubItems
                        oSubItem.ResetStyle()
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Have your exception handling code here!
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a Q&A site. If you have a question about an issue that you're having with that code then please ask it clearly.  If you want to share working code with others then this is not the place to do it.

Comment: Your comment "want to share working code with others then this is not the place to do it" is wrong and misleading. SOF in fact supports sharing working code for the benefit of others as it provides provision to ask question and simultaneously provide the answer as well (I missed this earlier but found out), with the intention of sharing code right?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the problem is but I based this on your code. Just changed the For loop to just selected items. Also, I didn't pass in the list view. This would only be necessary if the code was not in the form class or you have more than one listview. I also changed FullRowSelect to true at design time.

```
Private Sub OpCode(clrHighLightColor As System.Drawing.Color)
        Try
            If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Return
            For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
                lvi.BackColor = clrHighLightColor
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Have your exception handling code here!
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnChangeLVBackColor_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnChangeLVBackColor.Click
        Dim myColor As Color = Color.Red
        OpCode(myColor)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies, I was supposed to use the question and put the answer separate using include answer feature of SOF. When I realised, it was too late! Anyway thank for your help!